# How to pass a list of vectors to a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to pass a list of vectors to a lambda expression but I'm receiving compilation errors. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct data_t {
    int data;
    int some_other_data;
};

auto main() -> int {
    std::vector<data_t> v1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}};
    std::vector<data_t> v2 = {{6, 6}, {7, 7}, {8, 8}, {9, 9}, {10, 10}};

    const auto update_vectors = [&](auto& v, const auto& c, const auto pop) {
        for (auto& i : v) {
            if (pop) i.pop_back();
            i.push_back(c);
        }
    };

    auto d = data_t{11, 11};
    update_vectors({v1, v2}, d, true);

    return 0;
}
```

The errors I'm receiving are as follows:

```
error: no match for call to '(const main()::<lambda(const auto:1&, const auto:2&,     
auto:3)>) (<brace-enclosed initializer list>, data_t&, bool)'
   23 |     update_vectors({v1, v2}, d, true);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What am I doing wrong please and how to overcome this problem?

A live play area is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Pbqq1E157).

Comment: Wow, you really like `auto`, don't you? That is not always a good thing to use. C++ is a strongly types language and its good to be able to see the types you are working with. `auto v1 = std::vector<data_t>() = {...};` should be simplified to `std::vector<data_t> v1{...};` and `for (auto i : {v})` should be `for (auto &i : v)`.

Comment: In any case, I don't think `auto` can deduce a type from a brace-init-list, so use `std::initializer_list` explicitly instead, eg: `const auto update_vectors = [&](const std::initializer_list<std::vector<data_t>>& v, ...)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've updated the code with your first comment but it still fails. I've also (in the background) tried your second comment but that didn't work either. Any more ideas, please?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've tried your second comment again and got a different compilation error. Here's a godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/xTYM8q77e

Comment: You are not passing a list of vectors, you are trying to pass a vector of vectors based on your signature. Make up your mind :-)

Comment: `vector<vector<data_t>> v12{v1, v2};` and `update_vectors(v12, d, true);`.  For **auto** to work, it has to be able to deduce the type.  You've got no type for it to deduce in the code provided.

Comment: @Andrew oh, I forgot that `std::initializer_list` holds `const` elements, thus the `vector`s can't be modified inside the loop. If you use `std::array<std::vector<data_t>, 2>&& v` instead, then the code compiles. https://godbolt.org/z/WdEo14cPe. Or use a 2nd `std::vector` like Eljay suggested, that works, too

Comment: @Eljay That work, thank you. https://godbolt.org/z/EEzo8zx4s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think OP wants to pass a list of `std::vector` **references** to `update_vectors`. After calling `update_vectors()`, these `vector`s should be modified without generating extra copies.

This is exactly where [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) shines. Let me copy the description from cppreference

> std::reference_wrapper is a class template that wraps a reference in a copyable, assignable object. It is frequently used as a mechanism to store references inside standard containers (like std::vector) which cannot normally hold references.

That is to say, using a `std::vector<std::vector<data_t>>` cannot solve the problem. We should use `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<data_t>>>` instead.

[Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aee071fa7bde7877)

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct data_t {
  int data;
  int some_other_data;
};

auto main() -> int {
  std::vector<data_t> v1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}};
  std::vector<data_t> v2 = {{6, 6}, {7, 7}, {8, 8}, {9, 9}, {10, 10}};

  auto update_vectors = [](auto& vs, const auto& c, bool pop) {
    for (auto& v : vs) {
      if (pop) v.get().pop_back();
      v.get().push_back(c);
    }
  };

  auto d = data_t{11, 11};
  std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<data_t>>> v12{v1, v2};
  update_vectors(v12, d, true);

  std::cout << "v1 after calling update_vectors(): \n";
  for (auto it : v1) {
    std::cout << it.data << " " << it.some_other_data << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "v2 after calling update_vectors(): \n";
  for (auto it : v2) {
    std::cout << it.data << " " << it.some_other_data << std::endl;
  }
}
```

prints

```
v1 after calling update_vectors():
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
11 11
v2 after calling update_vectors():
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
11 11
```

Comment: Do you need the capture list?

Comment: Nice catch! The capture should be empty (`[]`). Answer updated.

Comment: It is just safer now